# CasperJS waitForResource for backbone Ajax times out even though the resource actually loads

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I add `.waitForResource`, which is timing out even though the resource successfully loads.

This is only on the Ajax calls made by our backbone/marionette application.

Adding logging on `resource.requested` and `resource.received` says that is has loaded, and our tests say all the data is there.

However, the test script hangs until the timeout fires.

I log when an AJAX resource has been requested, then we wait for it, and I log when its received, and I log when it times out.

`Requested` fires once, `Received` fires twice, and `timeout` fires once!!!!

```
Request id 149 : http://localhost:8080/my/resource
[info] [phantom] Wait for request 149 http://localhost:8080/my/resource
Received id 149 : http://localhost:8080/my/resource
Received id 149 : http://localhost:8080/my/resource
[error] [phantom] request for http://localhost:8080/my/resource timed out.
```

Anyone had this with backbone apps?

**UPDATE**

This is phantomJS 1.9.8, casperJS 1.1.0-beta3.

Here is a watered down example that reproduces this...

```
casper.options.logLevel= 'debug';
casper.options.verbose = true;

/**
 * Auto waitForResource on all Ajax requests.
 * Inserts a 250ms delay after load to allow any page renders with response
 */
casper.on("resource.requested", function (request){
    //is this Ajax..
    var isAjax = request.headers.some(function(header) {
        return (header.name == "X-Requested-With" && header.value == "XMLHttpRequest");
    });

    if(isAjax){
        this.log("Wait for request " + request.id + " " + request.url, 'info');
        this.waitForResource(request.url, function(){
            this.wait(250); //wait quarter of a sec for any page render after an ajax load...
        }, function(){
            this.log("request for " + request.url + " timed out.", 'error')
        }, 10000);
    }
});

casper.on("resource.received", function (response){
    this.log('Received :'+ response.id + " " + response.url, 'debug');
});


casper.test.begin('CMS Login : Odd Ajax issue ', function (test) {
    casper.start("http://localhost:8080/login")
        .wait(1000)
        .then(function() {
            this.fill('#login_form', { sign_in_username_email: 'test', sign_in_password: 'REDACTED'}, true);
        })
        .waitForUrl('http://localhost:8080')
        .thenOpen("http://localhost:8080/slides")
        .waitForSelector("#main_region .slides")
        .then(function() {
            test.assertExists('#main_region .slides .slide-item', 'Slides have been loaded');
        })
        .run(function() {
            test.done();
        });
});
```

And here is the truncated log.
You can see at the end, it waits for the Ajax request, receives it twice, says its finished the wait for, and then times out.

```
$ casperjs test tests/ui/auth/test.js
Test file: tests/ui/auth/test.js
# CMS Login : Odd Ajax issue
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 8 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://localhost:8080/login, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://localhost:8080/login, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Received :1 http://localhost:8080/login
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://localhost:8080/login"
[debug] [phantom] Received :1 http://localhost:8080/login
[debug] [phantom] Received :6 http://localhost:8080/resource/css/font-awesome.css?v=
[debug] [phantom] Received :7 http://localhost:8080/resource/css/style.css?v=

<-- more received files -->

[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[debug] [phantom] start page is loaded
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/8 http://localhost:8080/login (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/8: done in 1580ms.

<-- more received files -->

[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 1000ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/8 http://localhost:8080/login (HTTP 200)
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: '#login_form'
[debug] [remote] Set "sign_in_username_email" field value to test
[debug] [remote] Set "sign_in_password" field value to *********
[info] [remote] submitting form to http://localhost:8080/login/auth, HTTP POST
[info] [phantom] Wait for request 44 http://localhost:8080/login/auth
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/8: done in 2609ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 5/9 http://localhost:8080/login (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 5/9: done in 2610ms.
[debug] [phantom] Received :44 http://localhost:8080/login/auth
[debug] [phantom] Received :44 http://localhost:8080/login/auth
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://localhost:8080/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 215ms.
[debug] [phantom] Received :45 http://localhost:8080/
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://localhost:8080/"
[debug] [phantom] Received :45 http://localhost:8080/
[debug] [phantom] Received :48 http://localhost:8080/resource/css/presentations.css?v=

<-- more received files -->

[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 6/10 http://localhost:8080/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 6/10: done in 3566ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 7/11 http://localhost:8080/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 7/11: done in 3573ms.


<-- more received files -->

[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 250ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 8/11 http://localhost:8080/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 8/11: done in 3836ms.
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 42ms.
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://localhost:8080/slides, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://localhost:8080/slides, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Received :115 http://localhost:8080/slides
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://localhost:8080/slides"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Received :115 http://localhost:8080/slides

<-- more received files -->

[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step _step 10/11 http://localhost:8080/slides (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 10/11: done in 4389ms.

<-- more received files -->

[info] [phantom] Wait for request 149 http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435166114633
[debug] [phantom] Received :149 http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435166114633
[debug] [phantom] Received :149 http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435166114633
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 666ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 11/12 http://localhost:8080/slides (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 11/12: done in 5076ms.

[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
[error] [phantom] request for http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435166114633 timed out.

[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 12/12 http://localhost:8080/slides (HTTP 200)
PASS Slides have been loaded
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 12/12: done in 15112ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 12 steps in 15130ms

PASS 1 test executed in 15.134s, 1 passed, 0 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

**UPDATE**

This time, I removed my custom timeout handler, and only logged the resource received for the api call (which are all ajax requests).

You can see it does the wait, then says `[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 646ms.` and then a couple of lines later says `[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout`  But the received event still fires twice.  I have no clue...

```
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://localhost:8080/slides"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step _step 10/11 http://localhost:8080/slides (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 10/11: done in 4206ms.
[info] [phantom] Wait for request 142 http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435171549698
[debug] [phantom] Received :142 http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435171549698
[debug] [phantom] Received :142 http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435171549698
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 646ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 11/12 http://localhost:8080/slides (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 11/12: done in 4853ms.
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
FAIL http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435171549698 did not load in 5000ms
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: tests/ui/auth/test.js
#    error: http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435171549698 did not load in 5000ms

#    stack: not provided
FAIL 1 test executed in 9.885s, 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.

Details for the 1 failed test:

In tests/ui/auth/test.js
  CMS Login : API form validation
    uncaughtError: http://localhost:8080/api/slide?product_id=1&country_code=go&modal=false&page=1&limit=18&order_by=date_modified&order_direction=DESC&_=1435171549698 did not load in 5000ms
```

Comment: I just looked at the CasperJS source code and it seems that what you describe can't happen. Maybe you removed a little detail when changing the real URLs to example URLs. Also, please provide actual code. There are many ways to write a resource test function.

Comment: ok, Ill try to nock up a test case that I can add here....

Comment: @ArtjomB. Have updated the questions with more details...

Comment: Ok, I see. It looks fine. I think `waitForResource()` only fires when the resource that corresponds to the passed string was successfully loaded. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: waitForResource is firing though, its all working fine, EXCEPT that the time out also fires!   Ill add the other handlers though.   This didnt happen on a jquery ajax request, but does appear to happen on the backbone models.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Nothing extra came out of the error messages. Any other ideas ?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I removed my custom timeout handler and added the new log to the post.  It clearly does receive the data, but still timesout.  I'm at a loss  on this one...

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know how CasperJS handles wait requests that come in during another internal `then*` call.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Cheers for looking into it, I at least found out that the 2 calls to received is as expected.  One is 'start' and one is 'end' for the request.  Still looking into it...